# Checking how many connections are established on specified port

Tags: unix, freebsd, connection

How can I check, how many connections are established for example on port `80` and then write it to the file using bash console?

I've read that `netstat` can do this, but I can not find , what exactly should I do with that, as I'm newbie on "Unix" systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `sockstat` if you're on FreeBSD:

```
sockstat -c -L -P tcp -p 80
```

Comment: This show the information about connections, I wan't to get connections COUNT and then write it to the file.

Comment: @Cyclone Pipe it into `wc -l`. `sockstat ... wc - l`.